# Removing dataset columns with python slices

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2017-04-01 00:24:17','2017-04-01 00:54:16','2017-04-01 01:24:17'] * 1000, 'Luminosity':[2,3,4] * 1000})
```

The output of `dataframe` is this:

```
      Date                Luminosity
0   2017-04-01 00:24:17     2
1   2017-04-01 00:54:16     3
2   2017-04-01 01:24:17     4
.           .               . 
.           .               .
```

I want remove or select just the `Luminosity` column, then, with python slices I have the following:

```
X = dataframe.iloc[:, 1].values
# Give a new form of the data
X = X.reshape(-1, 1)
```

And the output of X is the following numpy array:

```
array([[2],
   [3],
   [4],
   ...,
   [2],
   [3],
   [4]])
```

I have the same situation, but a new dataframe with 76 columns, like [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GSS4lk598uiYDU7of-fWTqGaUjEJePAMgZlme8TxxXQ/edit?usp=sharing)

This is the output when I read it.

[image]

In total, the dataframe have 76 columns, I just want select 25 columns which are the columns named `PORVL2N1` , `PORVL2N2`, `PORVL4N1` and so successively
until arrive to the end column named `PORVL24N2` which is the `76th` column

For the moment, the solution that I have is create a new data frame only with the columns of my interest, this is:

```
a = df[['PORVL2N1', 'PORVL2N2', 'PORVL4N1', 'PORVL5N1', 'PORVL6N1', 'PORVL7N1', 
    'PORVL9N1', 'PORVL9N1', 'PORVL10N1', 'PORVL13N1', 'PORVL14N1', 'PORVL15N1',
    'PORVL16N1', 'PORVL16N2', 'PORVL18N1', 'PORVL18N2', 'PORVL18N3','PORVL18N4',
    'PORVL21N1', 'PORVL21N2', 'PORVL21N3', 'PORVL21N4', 'PORVL21N5', 'PORVL24N1',
    'PORVL24N2']
```

And the output is:

[image]

I want make the same, select just the columns of my interest, but using python slices with `iloc` to indexing and selecting by position, such as I make in the beginning of my question.

I know that this is possible with slides, but I cannot understand good the slices sintax to get it.

How to can I using `iloc` and slices python to select my interest columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering you have your data in dataframe `df`, you can do the following:

```
cols = list(df.columns)
pos_cols = [ i for i, word in enumerate(cols) if word.startswith('PORVL') ]
df.iloc[:, pos_cols]
```

Alternatively, you can use `.filter()` with `regex`.

```
df.filter(regex=("PORVL.*"))
```

Have a look at [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Use regular slice notation...

```
>>> df
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  2  2
2  3  3  3  3  3
3  4  4  4  4  4
4  5  5  5  5  5
>>> df.iloc[:,2:]
   c  d  e
0  1  1  1
1  2  2  2
2  3  3  3
3  4  4  4
4  5  5  5
>>> df.iloc[:,-2:]
   d  e
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3
3  4  4
4  5  5
>>>
```

[slice objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) also work

```
>>> last3 = slice(-3,None)
>>> df.iloc[:,last3]
   c  d  e
0  1  1  1
1  2  2  2
2  3  3  3
3  4  4  4
4  5  5  5
>>>
```

---

[Selection By Position](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-position)